# Looking for a PREV - NEXT page link generation script that will cycle alphabetically or numerically though all the .php pages within a directory

Tags: php, jquery, navigation, pagination

I'm looking for a PREV - NEXT page link generation script that will cycle alphabetically or numerically though all the .php pages within a directory.

I have a list of projects in a directory that I access from a menu page. Once the user chooses a project from the menu I'd really like to add a PREV and NEXT button to allow the user to cycle though the projects one at a time rather than having to go back to the menu page each time. *Of course I could hand code the links but thought it would be a great job for a script to handle.*

I really need it to be infinite as well, so when it reaches the last file in the directory the NEXT button is still active and will take you to the first item . ( From the first item the PREV button should take you to the last item )

I've been looking around for ages but so far found nothing that quite does the job.
The content of the pages is not coming from a database, but I've used some basic php includes for navigation blocks. I don't need anything other than simple NEXT and PREV controls either as there wont be a huge number of pages.

Any suggestions most appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the ids are numeric, this is very easy. Assuming the URL for displaying a project is:

```
http://myserver/project.php?id=3
```

...you just need to do something like:

```
  // Sanitise user input
  $currentId = (int) $_GET['id'];

  // Calculate next/prev IDs
  $nextId = $currentId + 1;
  $prevId = ($currentId > 1) ? $currentId - 1 : 1; // Make sure the previous ID is not below 1

  // Make links
  $nextLink = "<a href=\"project.php?id=$nextId\">Next</a>";
  $prevLink = "<a href=\"project.php?id=$prevId\">Previous</a>";
```

If you are doing it based on the file names themselves, it's a little more tricky - but only a little. You would need to get a list of files in the directory, and use them instead. Now we'll assume your URL's look like:

```
http://myserver/project.php?name=somefile
```

```
<?php

  // Sanitise user input
  $currentFile = basename($_GET['name']);

  // These will hold the previous/next project names
  $prev = $next = '';

  // Loop the directory until we find the current file
  $dp = opendir('.'); // Open current dir, this can be adjusted to your file structure
  while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== FALSE) {
    if (in_array($file, array('.','..')) continue; // Skip . and ..
    if ($file == $currentFile) {
      if (($file = readdir($dp)) !== FALSE) {
        $next = $file;
      }
      break;
    }
    $prev = $file;
  }
  closedir($dp);

  // Make links
  if ($next !== '') {
    $nextLink = '<a href="project.php?name='.htmlspecialchars($next).'">Next</a>';
  } else {
    // Handle no next project here
  }

  if ($prev !== '') {
    $prevLink = '<a href="project.php?name='.htmlspecialchars($prev).'">Previous</a>';
  } else {
    // Handle no previous project here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.

Not to sure how to implement this to my files though.

My files will be named something along the lines of:

project-01.php
project-02.php
project-03.php

None of the content is coming from a database.
Just some standard HTML with PHP includes for navigation, header, footer etc.